# Colspan alternative in <div> based structure

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to use `div` elements to create a table-like layout.

What I want

```css
.tableStyle td {
  background: red;
  color: #fff
}

.contentBox {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableStyle" width="100%" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">
      <div class="contentBox">One</div>
    </td>
    <td width="25%">Two</td>
    <td width="50%" colspan="2">Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="contentBox">Four</div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">Five</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I have

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  color: #fff
}

.table .row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table .table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.contentBox {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.table .smlCell {
  width: 25%;
}

.table .table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="table-cell smlCell">
            <div class="contentBox">One</div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-cell smlCell">
            Two
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="contentBox">Four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">Five</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to have equal spacing between the cells marked "One" and "Two".

I also want all cells in a row to be of same height.

After searching on net, I know that there are some limitations or issues 
for `display: table` such as a lack of colspan/rowspan equivalents which may help what I'm trying to accomplish.

Is there anyway (apart form `<table>`) to create this?

Comment: If you want to display your information in a table like structure then the `table` element is perfect for that. What's the reason you don't want to use tables?

Comment: Its not a table structure, if I don't get any solution than finally  I have no option other than table. Thanks for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure there is!

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cUW7/8/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='table'>
            <div class='cell'>One</div>
            <div class='cell'>Two</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cell'>Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>Four</div>
        <div class='cell'>Five</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    background:red;
    color:white;
    border:5px solid white;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, however I can not give border as there is box-shadow for every box.

Comment: Add `border-collapse:seperate;border-spacing: 3px;` to the `.table` class

Comment: This will give spacing from all side, however I want that in only between box "one" and "two".

Comment: What have you tried? See: http://jsfiddle.net/W4fR7/1/ -or- http://jsfiddle.net/W4fR7/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have used inline instead of CSS class. You had placed one div in wrong location.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="table-cell smlCell">
                        <div style="width:50% float: left" class="contentBox">One
                      </div>

                    <div style="width:50% float: right" class="contentBox">
                        Two
                    </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="contentBox">Four</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">Five</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with support for older (ms-explorer?).  But if your content is table by it's nature, use table and not those tricks :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bla!</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            /* reset sizing model ... */
            * { box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box; }
            /* basic div definitions */
            div { display:inline-block; min-height:50px; background-color:red; border:solid 3px white; }
            /* 1/2 line div */
            div.half { width:50%; }
            /* 1/4 line div */
            div.quater { width:25%; }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body class='body' id='body' >
        <div class='quater'> One </div><div class='quater'> Two </div><div class='half'> Three </div><div class='half'> Four </div><div class='half'> Five </div>

    </body>
</html>
```